# How to calculate the Fourier coefficients for $f(x) = 6x+2$ for $-\pi < x < \pi$.

Tags: definite-integrals, fourier-analysis

Consider the function $f \in C_{st}$ which satisfies that 
$$
f(x) = 6x+2
$$
for $-\pi < x < \pi$
Then I have to calculate the Fourier coefficients $c_n$.

MY ATTEMPT:

For $n=0$ we have that
$$
2\pi c_0 = \int_{-\pi}^\pi (6x+2)e^0 dx = \int_{-\pi}^\pi (6x+2) dx = \left[3x^2 + 2x\right]_{-\pi}^\pi = 4\pi
$$
Thus $c_0 = 2$. Is this alright? Furthermore, for $n \neq 0$ we notice that
$$
2\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{-inx}dx = 0
$$
Thus we only need to calculate
\begin{align*}
  2\pi c_n & = 6\int_{-\pi}^\pi xe^{-inx}dx \\
  & = 6 \left( \frac{1}{-in} \left[xe^{-inx}\right]_{-\pi}^\pi + \frac{1}{in} \int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{-inx} dx \right)\\
  & = 6 \left( \frac{1}{-in} \left( \pi e^{-in\pi} - (-\pi e^{in\pi} \right) \right) \\
  & = \frac{12\pi}{in}
\end{align*}
Thus $c_n = \frac{6}{in}$. Is this correct? I tried to type the integral in Wolframalpha and it gave something completely different.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's redo the computation, taking into account that
$\;\mathrm e^{in\pi}=\mathrm e^{-in\pi}=(-1)^n$:
\begin{align}
2\pi c_n & = 6 \biggl( \frac{1}{-in} \Bigl[xe^{-inx}\Bigr]_{-\pi}^\pi + \frac{1}{in} \int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{-inx} dx \biggr)\\
& =  6 \biggl(\frac{i}{n} \bigl(\pi\mathrm e^{-in\pi}+\pi\mathrm e^{in\pi}\bigr) + \frac{1}{n^2}e^{-inx}\Bigr|_{\pi}^\pi \biggr)\\
&=(-1)^n\frac{12i\pi}{n}.
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense. I am only a little bit unsure how $1/(-in)$ becomes $i/n$. Do you mind explaining?

Comment: Do we maybe multiply with the complex conjugate?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It is more or less standard that the reciprocal of $i$ is $-i$ (since $(-i)i=1$

Comment: Would that be necessary when rewriting the expression?

Comment: I don't think so. One may suppose the reader is smart enough to see what it's related to.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Bernard! :)

Comment: You're welcome. Does it correspond to Wolframalpha?

Comment: Wolframalpha says that it is $\frac{12i(\pi n cos(\pi n) - sin(\pi n))}{n^2}$. Is that the same?

Comment: It seems like Wolframalpha says that there is missing a $n$? as $ncos\left(\pi \:n\right)-sin\left(\pi \:n\right) = (-1)^nn$

Comment: It's the same, since $\cos n\pi=(-1)^n$ and $\sin n\pi=0$.